# using attributes of different objects in different objects methods

Tags: ruby

what i need is basically to use variable from one file, in the method. let me explain

lets say we have

```
class Game
attr_accessor :number, :object

end
```

where number is just some number and object is object of some other class defined by me, lets name it Player class. now we make another file, which requires class Game, and which goes like this:

```
require './Game.rb'
require './Player.rb'

myGame = Game.new
myGame.number = 1
myGame.object = Player.new
```

and now the big moment. in method defined in Player class, i would like to use myGame.number attribute. eg like this

```
class Player
attr_accessor :some_var

    def method
        @some_var = myGame.number
    end
end
```

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Your player should have a reference to the game is playing. For instance

```
class Game
    attr_accessor :number
    attr_reader :my_player

    def my_player=(player)
        player.my_game = self
        @my_player = player
    end
end

class Player
    attr_accessor :some_var, :my_game

  def method
     @some_var = @my_game.number if @my_game
  end
end

myGame = Game.new
myGame.number = 1
myGame.my_player = Player.new()

myGame.my_player.method

puts myGame.my_player.some_var
```

Comment: i don't get this line: player.my_game = self

Comment: @KubaPolaczek `self` refers to the current object, the game instance in this case.

Comment: @KubaPolaczek I've added an attribute `my_game` in `Player`. Check its class definition. And `player` is the reference to the `Player` object passed as a parameter.

Comment: nope, not really, but don't bother, i'm noob in ruby world, will do my best to figure this out, i still need my code to work;]

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to toch's answer, you can keep a reference to the game object when you set the player accessor. Instead of using automatic accessors you can use the [get_ set_ accessor syntax](http://www.rubyist.net/~slagell/ruby/accessors.html) to have custom code in the accessor, which would set the reference on the rvalue.